# Upload .SHP file to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, file-upload, geospatial, shapefile

I have `.shp` files that I want to upload to SQL Server and then combine with data and use in Tableau.

I am trying to find an easy solution to uploading `.shp` file to SQL Server 2017. I tried OGR2OGR and I get an error. Below is my OGR2OGR command and then the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgSRB.png)

I tried Shape2SQL from https://www.sharpgis.net/page/shape2sql but when I go to upload the file, nothing happens.

Comment: To make this question more actionable, post OGR2OGR command and full output. It should work with valid shapefiles (.shp and related files in same directory) and correct command.

Comment: Hi Michael, I've attached my OGR2OGR error to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a missing space in the command.

Error message references ....shp-a_srs, obviously because of missing space between shape file name and -a_srs flag made command line parser treat it as one. Add space and try again.